# Cake Build auto merge functionality

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, cakebuild

I'm using [cakebuid](https://cakebuild.net/) as my build tool for [TFS 2017 Update 2](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs2017-update2) and trying to implement the traditional [Git Flow](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html). In this flow, there are a few automatic merges that happen every time changes get into **master**, those changes need to be propagated to the **develop** branch.
Using cake I can run a PowerShell script or use [LibGit2Sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki) to accomplish the automatic merge for the best case scenarios. But, what about when the merge has conflicts? Do I need to fail the whole build because the merge process fail?
We have certainly something to deal with merges in TFS, this is no other than the **Pull Request**.

*Question*

> Is there any tool or add-in for **cake** that allows me to create
>   **Pull Request** during the execution of a build step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I spend sometimes creating the package:

Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cake.Tfs.AutoMerge

GitHub: https://github.com/mabreuortega/Cake.Tfs

The way you can use it now is similar to this:

```
Task("Merge")
    .Does(c => {
        CreateAutoMergePullRequest(
            new AutoMergeSettings 
            {
                        // Required
                CollectionUri = "https://{instance}/{collection-name}",
                ProjectName = "project-name",
                RepositoryName = "repository-name",
                SourceBranch = "refs/heads/release/1.0.0",
                TargetBranch = "refs/heads/develop",
                Title = "[Auto Merge from Release]",

                        // Optional
                Description = "Brief description of the changes about to get merge",

                        // Control
                DeleteSourceBranch = false,
                SquashMerge = false,
                OverridePolicies = true,
                AutoComplete = true,
                AutoApprove = true
            });
    });
```

Any suggestions, please use the GitHub issue tracker.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any add-in available for you to create a pull request but since you can run PowerShell, you can easily use the TFS rest api to create pull request

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/pull-requests/pull-requests

Answer (score 2):

It was recently announced that there is a VSTS CLI:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/11/15/introducing-the-new-cli-for-vsts/

Which includes the ability to create a pull request:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cli/vsts/get-started?view=vsts-cli-latest#create-a-pull-request

I don't think it would be particularly hard to create a Cake Addin which wraps this tool, and exposes the functionality through a set of addin's.

In the mean time, you could shell out to this tool using the [Process aliases](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common/ProcessAliases/) that currently exist in Cake.